# Why skip() and take() not works when I use getRawMany() in nestJS with typeorm?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Here is the code I currently use.

with getRawMany() - skip and take not works!

```js
const data = await getRepository(Enquiry)
  .createQueryBuilder('enq')
  .select([
    'enq.id AS id',
    'enq.location AS location',
    'enqStatus.name AS status'
  ])
  .leftJoin('enq.status', 'enqStatus')
  .skip(1)
  .take(3)
  .where(payload)
  .getRawMany()
```

Comment: you need leftJoinAndSelect, late answer but I think it will work ~

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with limit and offset

```
const data = await getRepository(Enquiry)
  .createQueryBuilder('enq')
  .select([
    'enq.id AS id',
    'enq.location AS location',
    'enqStatus.name AS status'
  ])
  .leftJoin('enq.status', 'enqStatus')
  .where(payload)
  .offset(meta.page)
  .limit(meta.pageSize)
  .getRawMany()
```

Comment: I tried this but not worked! :(

Comment: Did you try with `limit` and `offset`? I think the `leftJoin` would cause this issue.

Comment: limit and offset works! Thank bro :)

Comment: in conjunction joins this will not work as expected as it limits to total of all child-records (e.g. joining an article with keywords, then you'll get only one article but 3 keywords when doing "limit 3"